# Store the JSONObject Value in Database as individual entity within database

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've a JSON Like this

```
  {
 "dlCovs":
   {
 "covabbrv":["MCWG","LMV"],
 "dcIssuedt":["01-11-2011  XYZ","01-11-2011  XYZ"],
"vecatg":["01-11-2011  XYZ ","01-11-2011  XYZ"],"status":"valid"},
 "status":"valid"
   }
```

I have the Following Code

```
   if (dlCovs.has("vecatg")) {
            this.COVCategory = dl_covData.getJSONObject("dlCovs").getJSONArray("vecatg").toString();
            // this.COVCategory = dl_covData.get("vecatg").toString();
        }
        if (dlCovs.has("covabbrv")) {
            // this.classOfVehicle = dl_covData.get("covabbrv").toString();
            this.classOfVehicle = dl_covData.getJSONObject("dlCovs").getJSONArray("covabbrv").toString();
        }
        if (dlCovs.has("dcIssuedt")) {
            // this.issueDate = dl_covData.get("dcIssuedt").toString();
            this.issueDate = dl_covData.getJSONObject("dlCovs").getJSONArray("dcIssuedt").toString();
        }
```

Problem is it's storing the entir String Value into database, 
like as against the value of "covabbrv" is storing the value like ["MCWG","LMV"]
but i want all of these value present within the array should be stored Individually like MCWG as a single entity and LMV as another entity in datbase,
any help will be highly appreciable, thanks well in advance.

Comment: mention what database you r using

Comment: @smn_onrocks i'm using mySQL database, the problem is not with the database actually the problem is more likely of logical level as compared to  database persistence level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalize your database to make sure you have only atomic fields in each column. And to avoid duplicates, you will want to split your table into two tables. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

In your case you need a separate table with covabbrv's with a forign key to your main table, so you can have multiple covabbrv's for one main entity.

You can write your own code for that, but since you're using Java, I'd suggest mapping your JSON to a Java Entity class, and use @ElementCollection annotation for the covabbrv field, as described here: 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Example_of_an_ElementCollection_relationship_to_a_basic_value_database

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dlCovs.has("vecatg")) {
        this.COVCategory = dl_covData.getJSONObject("dlCovs").getJSONArray("vecatg").toString();
        // this.COVCategory = dl_covData.get("vecatg").toString();
    }
    if (dlCovs.has("covabbrv")) {
        JSONArray classOfVehicle = dl_covData.getJSONObject("dlCovs").getJSONArray("covabbrv");

        for(int i = 0; i < classOfVehicle.length(); i++)
        {
             String item = classOfVehicle.getString(i);
             // now you can save item in database
        }
    }
    if (dlCovs.has("dcIssuedt")) {
        // this.issueDate = dl_covData.get("dcIssuedt").toString();
        this.issueDate = dl_covData.getJSONObject("dlCovs").getJSONArray("dcIssuedt").toString();
    }
}
```

You first need to get JSONArray of "covabbrv" then loop through jsonArray to get individual items

Comment: it's their Buddy
"covabbrv":["MCWG","LMV"], like you can see from the above JSON, even if it's not their can you just ignore that case and can you please tell me to iterate over it

Comment: didn't get you, can u elaborate what u want